# How to edit gnome/unity menus without using Alacarte?

Tags: unity, gnome, unity-dash

Alacarte crashes every time I attempt to edit a submenu or move an item from one submenu to another and then I'd have to wipe the application.menu files or my gnomeshell desktop would be useless. Is there a way to organize my main menu and unity dash applications subcategories without using Alacarte? I've got so many items installed in the wrong category and I'd also like to remove a ton of zombie icons.

Comment: I can edit and correct some information using these responses, but one large question remains unanswered. How do I move entries that gnome misfiled in the 'other' menu during my last upgrade, and put them back where they belong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**GUI way**

You might want to try [Menulibre](https://launchpad.net/menulibre), a new alternative to Alacarte. You can install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

**Manual way**

Application launchers are located in these three folders:

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

(your user only)

```
/usr/local/share/applications
/usr/share/applications
```

(all users)

By modifying the `.desktop` files found in these folders you can edit menu entries directly. Modifications in user-wide folders will require root access:

```
gksudo nautilus /usr/local/share/applications
```

Drag and drop `.desktop` files into a text editor like gedit to edit their contents. If root access is required, use:

```
gksudo gedit
```

Delete the files to remove their corresponding menu/dash entries.

**Important Caveat**: Changes introduced to default – i.e. user-wide – `.desktop` files might get reverted on the next system update.

Comment: Application launchers for all users are usually located in `/usr/share/applications`. `/usr/local/share/applications` usually only contains launchers for programs that you install from source code. Also, you can edit a launcher from one of those two folder as a normal user: copy the launcher to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit that copy (that's what alacarte and menulibre do). Only you will see this modified launcher.

Comment: @BrunoNova Thanks for the correction on the launcher locations! I'd only like to add that copying the launcher to your home folder might result in a duplicate launcher in the dash. OTOH, changes introduced to the default launchers might get reverted with system updates.

Comment: How to change item location in the menu?

Answer (score 8):

To add to the answer above, the .desktop files may also be located in

```
/usr/share/applications
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative menu editor is [ezame](https://launchpad.net/~caldas-lopes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) which I have used and works quite well. You can install it by running the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caldas-lopes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ezame
```

The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/linux-man/ezame).

Answer (score 0):

An old alternative is to install gnome-panel and use gnome-desktop-item-edit application.

`gnome-desktop-item-edit` also has a parameter `--create-new`, to create new launchers.